# OpenID Connect with Gluu server and pac4j/shiro client - cannot get token - invalid_client

Tags: java, openid-connect

I have started to deploy a user authentication solution consisting of Gluu at authentication server side with OpenID connect, and pac4j-oidc at client.

I registered the client manually. I have also put the same credentials to shiro config. Then when I try to log in - first I see the login form of Gluu server (if I am not logged in yet) and at making a query to TokenEndpoint I have an error.

The error response:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed (e.g. unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method). The authorization server MAY return an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code to indicate which HTTP authentication schemes are supported. If the client attempted to authenticate via the Authorization request header field, the authorization server MUST respond with an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code, and include the WWW-Authenticate response header field matching the authentication scheme used by the client."}
```

After I looked at the logs, I see such some error. I pasted to pastebin, cause there is too many urls (local ones but still) inside to post them here.

http://pastebin.com/H7xBMY1J

Please help me, I seat second day trying to resolve it :(

Comment: It seems like the client id when EntryPersistenceException happens is url-encoded - probably shouldn't be.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?  We are currently seeing the same behavior.